# compiled nx-react-app project shows environment variables in plain text

Tags: reactjs, production-environment, nomachine-nx, .env, nx-monorepo

When I compile my project in react on monorepo nx for production. The file contains environment variables in plain text. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I tried using cmd-env to load them. I tried using environments.ts to prod by sexting the variables directly from my OS via export. Each of my attempts fails.